# Firebase - Open URL if data payload contains link, else open the app

Tags: java, firebase, hashmap, firebase-cloud-messaging

From my potato server API, I have 2 textbox, which is the message and link field.

My goal is to allow the users to open the link I sent, whenever the payload contains "link", else will just open the app by default.

I'm thinking to separate the payload(Map) into some variables(if it's possible), then if the variable of "link" not equals to NULL, I will change the click_action to open the link.

Is this a good approach ?

My log.d shows this when 2 box are filled

`Message data payload: {link=google.com, message=click this}`

And this, if I leave link's field blank.

```
Message data payload: {message=hello}
```

Comment: wow chigga is so pro